# Error executing Puppeteer from PHP

Tags: php, apache, centos7, puppeteer

I have a node script which converts a webpage into a PDF document. The user enters some content and PHP builds a HTML page, which then is used in a node script (that runs Puppeteer, using a slightly modified version of [an example script](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#usage)) to convert it to PDF.

But when I [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) in PHP the command to run the node script, it fails with the following error:

```
(node:14832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[0424/165455.239499:ERROR:icu_util.cc(133)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
[0424/165455.239717:FATAL:content_main_delegate.cc(53)] Check failed: false.
#0 0x55f27f255b0c base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x55f27f26e780 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x55f27d5f7d23 content::ContentMainDelegate::TerminateForFatalInitializationError()
#3 0x55f27ef90deb content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#4 0x55f27ef9ab72 service_manager::Main()
#5 0x55f27ef8ff14 content::ContentMain()
#6 0x55f28309f9b9 headless::(anonymous namespace)::RunContentMain()
#7 0x55f28309fa42 headless::HeadlessBrowserMain()
#8 0x55f27ef97f9d headless::HeadlessShellMain()
#9 0x55f27d5f61ac ChromeMain
#10 0x7efcaad45c05 __libc_start_main
#11 0x55f27d5f602a _start
```

PHP is running with the `apache` user. However, if I run the same script with my user, it works perfectly. When I execute in a terminal using `su - apache -c 'node ...'` it again throws the error described above.

What is causing the error? Something related to apache user's permissions? I've followed all troubleshotting guides but I had no luck at the moment.

Comment: So is this an issue with puppet or node? Seems like node.

Comment: @Anthony Apparently it's a problem with puppeteer. If I remove all code related to Puppeteer and do for example some console logs, node runs fine.

Comment: Where is this running? My suspicon is that Chrome is missing a package or dependency (unless this is running locally)

Comment: @griffith_joel Chromium was installed along with 'puppeteer' package in node. I've also installed all dependencies found in docs. Anyway, I've just finally manage to get it work. I'm going to post an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the file-system permissions on the default chromium used by puppeteer:

using ACL( my nginx group is `www-data`, change with yours for apache):

`sudo setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rX  node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/`

and

`sudo setfacl -dR -m g:www-data:rX  node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/`

after setting the permissions the error went away.

Answer (score 4):

I was using the bundled version of Chromium which comes along with the Puppeteer library (as installed using `npm install puppeteer`).

Instead of using that version, I tried to install Chromium system-wide and give the node script the path to the system-wide installation of Chromium. It finally works, this version doesn't have that weird issue!

To execute Puppeteer using another executable:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    headless: true,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
});
```

I will look for other answers if there's another solution instead of installing Chromium on the system.

**Edit:**

Now there's a `puppeteer-core` package on NPM that doesn't bundle Chromium.