# Puppeteer don´t run with cronjobs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser

I want to run node.js process as a cron job, but process are not running well.

My javascript code is just the first puppeteer example available in docs (https://pptr.dev/):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'),
      process   = require('process')
;

(async () => {

    console.log( 'process owner: ' + process.env.USER );

    console.log('browser launch');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    console.log('browser launched, open new page');
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    console.log('Go to example.com');
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.screenshot({path: process.env.USER + '_example.png'});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

I've added username to validate the user that's running the script and cron job is this:

```
01 * * * * /usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node /var/node/pupp_test/init.js > /var/node/pupp_test/output.txt
```

So, if I run manually the script:

```
process owner: franco
browser launch
browser launched, open new page
Go to example.com
```

But, when script runs with cronjob, output file is just:

```
process owner: franco
browser launch
```

I don't understand why Puppeteer has this problem if the process owner is the same with bash and cron

I have node.js installed with NVM and configured Puppeteer with [setup setuid sandbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#alternative-setup-setuid-sandbox), so I can run node and puppeteer with all users in the machine.

Searching about my problem, I've find a topic talking about [executing Puppeteer from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174004/2287350) and I've already try with `setfacl` in `node_modules/puppeter/.local-chromium/` and in `/usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox`, but does not resolve my issue

- OS is Centos 7
- Node version is 10.16.0
- Puppeteer version is 1.19.0

Comment: is there a reason your using cronjob ? why dont you use pm2 or packages like that

Comment: I'm a nodejs newbien and i didn't know about that kind of node packages. Thanks @max for your comment :D

Comment: @max But I don't want my script to be kept alive forever. I only want to run it 3 times a day, and be able to see it run when it does.

Also check this out: askubuntu.com/a/239511/505581 Can it be related to our problem?

Comment: @max I already tried that when I asked in [Gitlab Project](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4759), but it doesn't work. Also, I no longer work on that project, so I can't even try any more solutions.

Comment: @vaibhavS you can use `setinterval` to run your code several time per day .. u don't need cronjob

Comment: However you run this, it's a good idea to put `browser.close()` in a `finally` block. If something throws unexpectedly, the process might not terminate.